# Engineering Numbers: Looking for a check code

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography, coding-theory

Not sure if this is the best place to ask but I own an engineering company.

We have expanded and I need a way to ensure part numbers are not entered incorrectly.

Part numbers are of the form:

$$Aaaxxx-xxxx-c$$

Ignore the the dash '-' characters, they are just there to make things more readable and are not stored in the database.

'A' is a single character [A..Z] or one of '!', '~', '#' or '$'
'a' is a single character [A..Z], 
'x' is a digit [0..9]

I have yet to define 'c' this is intended to be a check character to ensure no bad entries.

Typical typing errors are:

- Swapping two characters
- Entering the wrong one

I am looking for suggestions on where I can look to find an algorithm to define 'c'.

I am not worried about trying to correct an error only to recognise it.

Comment: The [check digit for ISBNs](https://php.mmc.school.nz/archived/2016/301BH/caitlinherring/2015ALL/201COS/91371/Computer%20Science/dtcsinformation/error-control/error-detection.html) might be of interest (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number). Also [these slides](https://www.uu.edu/dept/math/SeniorPapers/01-02/Oldham.pdf) and [this book](https://www.maa.org/press/books/identification-numbers-and-check-digit-schemes) seem on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can use the following code to calculate the last symbol for an arbitrary input string. The function is based on built-in MD5 function. MD5 function is very sensitive to input - the output changes drasticly for minor input changes. The function is slightly adjusted to ignore dashes and spaces in the input string.

```
import hashlib

def calculateLast(s):
    # set of symbols from which the last symbol will be picked
    # feel free to change it 
    checkSymbol = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    s1 = s.replace('-', '').replace(' ', '').encode()
    h = hashlib.md5(s1).hexdigest()
    num = int(h, 16)
    index = num % len(checkSymbol)
    return checkSymbol[index]    

print(calculateLast("Axz - 243 - 5847"))
```

MD5 is not the fastest way to compute a hash (on the contrary). But on modern computers it's not at issue. And you will find MD5 implementations in all modern programming languages.

Comment: It's good since MD5 is ready-to-use algorithm, but at the same time it is a bit overkill because you still reduce the result to one of few possibilities with equal probabilities.. Then  MD5 does not bring too much of its usual benefit - which is many output values, smaller chance for collisions (the drastic change of the output might not be that drastic in this case).

Comment: @Sil I just looked for something that is very easy for implementation (actuallly, I could have squeezed the code into 3 lines) with a fair chance to surve for the purpose. Reading big books just to calculate a single byte looks like overkill to me.

Comment: I agree, although check digit algorithms are designed to have specific goals in mind (protection against consecutive digits transpositions, single digit error, etc...), while MD5 was not designed for this and acts rather unpredictable. It really depends on use-case/requirements...